# How do I get the last child in a django-mptt tree?

Tags: django-mptt

I want to access the latest object a django-mptt tree.

Is it possible to do this from a django template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python code, you can use the [get_children](http://code.google.com/p/django-mptt/source/browse/trunk/mptt/models.py#26) method. This should work:

```
children = node.get_children()
if children:
    last_child = list(children)[-1]
```

To use this in a template, you'd need to write a simple template tag:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def last_child(node):
    children = node.get_children()
    if children:
        return list(children)[-1]
    else:
        return ""
```

Have a look at the [Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to find out how to integrate this tag into your project.

Comment: This looks great, but I get this error:

    Caught an exception while rendering: Negative indexing is not supported.

Comment: sorry, forgot to turn the queryset into a list. Fixed

Comment: great, now this works! :-)
small note if anyone copies this code: 
return = list(children)[-1] in the simple_tag should of course be 
return list(children)[-1]

Comment: again, sorry for not testing my code before answering. My train was just about to enter the train station and I hadn't time to test it